# Trace norm and Bures distance

Tags: operator-theory, adjoint-operators

I am given that the Bures distance between two density matrices (i.e. semi positive-definite self-adjoint maps which have trace equal to unity) $\rho_1,\rho_2$ is: $D_B(\rho_1,\rho_2) = 2(1-\|\rho_1^{1/2} \rho_{2}^{1/2}\|)$ where $\|\cdot\|$ is the $L^1$-norm defined by $\|A\| = \mathrm{Tr}(\sqrt{A^\star A})$,

I try to prove that $D_B(\rho_1,\rho_2) =0 \implies \rho_1 = \rho_2$.

I have already proven that $0\leq D_B(\rho_1,\rho_2)\leq 2$. My attempt is to write using that $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho_1) = \mathrm{Tr}(\rho_2) = 1$:

$$1 = \|\rho_1^{1/2}\rho_{2}^{1/2}\| = \|\rho_1\| = \|\rho_2\|,$$

however does it follow from this that $\rho_1 = \rho_2$ should hold?

Comment: Note that the quantity $ || \rho_{1}^{1/2} \rho_{2}^{1/2} || $ is the square root of fidelity. Try to do it for pure states first, and then if you are familiar with Uhlmann's theorem, generalize to mixed states.

Comment: I am not familiar with Uhlmann's theorem. Is there another quick way of proving this result or only from Uhlmann theorem?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with a proof that's shorter than the one using Uhlmann's theorem. It is worth learning, as it is one of the most powerful tools in quantum information theory.

Comment: these are matrices $\in \mathbb C^{n\times n}$, right?

Comment: @user8675309 I think that may suffice as I am doing physics rather than mathematics right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually this is very simple -- just write this out in a particularly nice way and apply Cauchy Schwarz.

It suffices the show $\|\rho_1^{1/2} \rho_{2}^{1/2}\|=\|\rho_1^{1/2} \rho_{2}^{1/2}\|_{S_1}\leq 1$ with equality *iff* $\rho_{1}=\rho_{2}$. I include the $S_1$ since this is a Schatten 1 norm.

It is also convenient to quasi-linearize the Schatten 1 norm by writing it as
$\Big \Vert A \Big \Vert_{S_1}=\max_U \Big \vert \text{trace}\big(U^*A\big)\Big\vert$ with $U\in U_n$.  This comes the from Polar Decomposition of $A$ (with optional use (i) of von Neumann Trace Inequality to verify the maximum or (ii) diagonalize the HPSD matrix in A's Polar Decomposition and apply triangle inequality when writing out the trace).

**Proof**
$\|\rho_1^{1/2} \rho_{2}^{1/2}\|_{S_1}$
$=\max_U \Big \vert \text{trace}\Big(U^*\rho_1^\frac{1}{2} \rho_2^\frac{1}{2}\Big) \Big \vert $
$=\max_U \Big \vert \text{trace}\Big(\big(U^*\rho_1^\frac{1}{2}\big) \rho_2^\frac{1}{2}\Big) \Big \vert $
$=\max_U \Big \vert \text{trace}\Big(\big(\rho_2^\frac{1}{2}\big)\big(U^*\rho_1^\frac{1}{2}\big)\Big) \Big \vert $
$=\max_U \Big \vert \text{trace}\Big(\big(\rho_2^\frac{1}{2}\big)^*\big(U^*\rho_1^\frac{1}{2}\big)\Big) \Big \vert $
$\leq\Big \Vert \rho_2^\frac{1}{2}\Big \Vert_F\cdot \Big \Vert U^*\rho_1^\frac{1}{2}\Big \Vert_F$
$= \text{trace}\big(\rho_2\big)^\frac{1}{2}\cdot \text{trace}\big(\rho_1\big)^\frac{1}{2}$
$= 1 \cdot 1$
$=1$
with equality *iff*  $\rho_1 = \rho_2$

*further explanation:*
examining the equality conditions of Cauchy Schwarz, which imply $\eta \cdot U^*\rho_1^\frac{1}{2} = \rho_2^\frac{1}{2}$
$1=\vert \eta\vert^2\cdot \Big\Vert U^*\rho_1^\frac{1}{2}\Big \Vert_F^2=\vert \eta\vert^2\cdot\text{trace}\big(\rho_1\big)= \text{trace}\big(\rho_2\big)=1\implies \eta$ is on the unit circle.

Thus we can say
$Q\rho_1^\frac{1}{2} = \big(\eta \cdot U^*\big)\rho_1^\frac{1}{2} = \rho_2^\frac{1}{2}$
$\implies \rho_1^\frac{1}{2}Q^* = \rho_2^\frac{1}{2}$
$\implies \rho_1=\big(\rho_1^\frac{1}{2}Q^*\big)\big(Q\rho_1^\frac{1}{2}\big)=\big(\rho_1^\frac{1}{2}Q^*\big)\rho_2^\frac{1}{2}=\rho_2^\frac{1}{2}\rho_2^\frac{1}{2} =\rho_2$